# Connect with DHCP server and get IP address

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, mikroc

I want to get a IP address from DHCP server to my PIC 18F4520 device, and I used mikroc SPI Ethernet Library to program my PIC. I made a code and it is not working. I want to get IP address and display it on a LCD.Can any one help me how to do that?

```
#include  "__EthEnc28j60.h"
#include  "__EthEnc28j60Private.h"


// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at LATB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at LATB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at LATB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at LATB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at LATB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at LATB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
// End LCD module connections

/*// SD module connections
sbit Mmc_Chip_Select           at LATC0_bit;  // for writing to output pin always use latch 

(PIC18 family)
sbit Mmc_Chip_Select_Direction at TRISC0_bit;
// End SD module connections*/

//ENC28j60 connection
sbit SPI_Ethernet_CS at LATC1_bit;
sbit SPI_Ethernet_Rst at LATC0_bit;

sbit SPI_Ethernet_CS_Direction at TRISC1_bit;
sbit SPI_Ethernet_Rst_Direction at TRISC0_bit;
//End ENC28j60 connection

const char httpHeader[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: "; // HTTP header
const char httpMimeTypeHTML[] = "text/html\n\n";             // HTML MIME type
const char httpMimeTypeScript[] = "text/plain\n\n";          // TEXT MIME type

// default html page
char    indexPage[] =
"<html><head><title>mikroElektronika</title></head><body>\
<h3 align=center>MikroElektronika Home Automatization System</h3>\
<form name=\"input\" action=\"/\" method=\"get\">\
<table align=center width=200 bgcolor=#4974E2 border=2><tr>\
<td align=center colspan=2><font size=4 color=white><b>Heat Control</b></font>\
</td></tr><tr><td align=center bgcolor=#4974E2><input name=\"tst1\" width=60 \
type=\"submit\" value=\"ON\"></td><td align=center bgcolor=#FFFF00>\
<input name=\"tst2\" type=\"submit\" value=\"OFF\"></td></tr></table>\
</form></body></html>";

// network parameters
char   myMacAddr[6] = {0x00, 0x14, 0xA5, 0x76, 0x19, 0x3f}; // my MAC address
char   myIpAddr[4]  = {0, 0, 0, 0};                         // my IP address


unsigned char   getRequest[20];                                    // HTTP request buffer

unsigned int  SPI_Ethernet_UserTCP(unsigned char *remoteHost, unsigned int remotePort, 

unsigned int localPort, unsigned int reqLength, TEthPktFlags *flags)
{
  unsigned int    len;                            // my reply length
  if(localPort != 80) return(0);             // I listen only to web request on port 80

  // get 10 first bytes only of the request, the rest does not matter here
  for(len = 0 ; len < 15 ; len++) getRequest[len] = SPI_Ethernet_getByte();
  getRequest[len] = 0;

  if(memcmp(getRequest, "GET /", 5)) return(0);  // only GET method

  if(!memcmp(getRequest+11, "ON", 2))        // do we have ON command
    PORTB.F0 = 1;                // set PORTB bit0
  else
    if(!memcmp(getRequest+11, "OFF", 3))        // do we have OFF command
      PORTB.F0 = 0;        // clear PORTB bit0

  if (PORTB.F0)
    {
     memcpy(indexPage+340, "#FFFF00", 6);        // highlight (yellow) ON
     memcpy(indexPage+431, "#4974E2", 6);        // clear OFF
    }
  else
    {
     memcpy(indexPage+340, "#4974E2", 6);        // clear ON
     memcpy(indexPage+431, "#FFFF00", 6);        // highlight (yellow) OFF
    }

  len =  SPI_Ethernet_putConstString(httpHeader);               // HTTP header
  len += SPI_Ethernet_putConstString(httpMimeTypeHTML);  // with HTML MIME type
  len += SPI_Ethernet_putString(indexPage);                           // HTML page first part
  return len; // return to the library with the number of bytes to transmit
}
unsigned int  SPI_Ethernet_UserUDP(unsigned char *remoteHost, unsigned int remotePort, 

unsigned int destPort, unsigned int reqLength, TEthPktFlags *flags)

{
  return 0; // back to the library with the length of the UDP reply
}


unsigned long  i, size, j, k;
char           filename[14] = "ASHAN.TXT";          // File names
int txt2,*pi;
unsigned short character[20];
unsigned short *contentBuffer;



void main(){

ADCON1 |= 0x0D;             // Configure AN0 and AN1 pins as analog
CMCON  |= 7;                // coparators off

TRISA = 0xff ;
PORTA = 0 ;

PORTB = 0 ;  //PORTB output
TRISB = 0 ;

PORTC = 0 ;
TRISC = 0b11011100 ;    // set PORTC as input except for bits 0 (RESET) and 1 (CS)

Delay_ms(100);

//Initialize LCD
Lcd_Init();
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF );
Lcd_Out(1, 1, "Status:");
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_SECOND_ROW);

SPI1_Init();
SPI_Ethernet_Init(myMacAddr, myIpAddr,1);

SPI_Ethernet_initDHCP(5); // get network configuration from DHCP server, wait 5 sec   for the response
memcpy(myIpAddr, Spi_Ethernet_getIpAddress(),4) ; // get assigned IP address
Lcd_Out_Cp(myIpAddr);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First think I'd do it's to run Wireshark and see if your DHCP discovery hits the wire or not, from that point you decide where the troubleshooting must be focused on...